# Uso mais comum para "O pai tá on"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, girias, uso-mais-comum

Por convivência, já ouvi homens usarem este termo para literalmente dizer que estão *online* em um determinado aplicativo, no entanto, também ouvi recentemente que poderia ser relacionado com *um homem dizendo que está aberto a relações (sexual casual ou amorosa)*.

Diz que o termo surgiu do [Neymar no time de futebol do Paris Saint German](https://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/2020/08/o-que-quer-dizer-o-pai-ta-on-veja-significado-do-meme-criado-por-neymar.ghtml), significando que *ele estava preparado pro jogo*. O termo original nunca ouvi alguém usar, além do próprio jogador.

Qual seria o uso mais comum e o seu contexto?

Comment: Talvez "estar pronto", parecido com o inglês "on" (ligado, ativo, ativado, operativo, funcionando), como "I am on"; ex.: "she left me yesterday. Well, now I am on!" (Ela me deixou ontem. Bom, agora eu estou ativo/operativo). No inglês, é comum usar a preposição assim, no final. O significado funciona com o que tu e a Soraia Silva dissestes.

Comment: Essa expressão surgiu muito recentemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A explicação mais razoável da frase do Neymar](https://www.metropoles.com/colunas/leo-dias/o-pai-ta-on-neymar-viraliza-expressao-do-momento-e-famosos-entram-na-onda)

Colunas
Leo Dias
19/08/2020 21:30,atualizado 19/08/2020 21:37

> "O pai tá on: Neymar viraliza expressão do momento e famosos entram na
> onda Léo Santana, Pedro Scooby e Rafael Zulu contam o que significa,
> para eles, o mote do craque brasileiro
>
> Neymar, que perdeu as decisões do Paris Saint-Germain na Champions
> League nas duas últimas temporadas, agora parece mais focado do que
> nunca a dar o tão sonhado título ao PSG. Mas isso não quer dizer que
> ele tenha deixado o jeito moleque de lado. Antes da vitória por 3 a 0
> contra o RB Leipzig, nessa terça-feira (18/8), o camisa 10 tuitou:
> “Passando pra avisar que o PAI acordou ONLINE. Salve pra geral e vamo
> que vamo … ALLEZ PSG”.
>
> Foi o suficiente para fazer com que a expressão ganhasse ainda mais
> vida além dos campos, sendo usada por várias celebridades. A coluna
> aproveitou para conversar com algumas delas e tentar saber: o que quer
> dizer “o pai tá on”? “Para mim, ela significa ‘tamo ativo, tamo
> esperto, tamo pra jogo, tamo na crista da onda, tamo no topo
> (risos)'”, disse Léo Santana.
>
> O ator Rafael Zulu, que também adotou o mote para a vida, explica o
> que sente ao dizê-lo: “Para mim, ‘o pai tá on’ significa que a
> pessoa, seja ela qual for, está pronta pro que vier pela frente”,
> resumiu. Até a galera do surfe decidiu aplicar o slogan. “Tô na ativa,
> hein? To na área, hein?! É uma gíria muito específica para aquele
> momento. Você acha que eu tô morto? Tô morto não, estou ligadíssimo”,
> comentou Pedro Scooby, aos risos.
>
> A frase de Neymar virou até filtro no Instagram, feito pelo canal
> Esporte Interativo. Luciano Huck, Gabriel Medina, Thiaguinho e Thiago
> Leifert também entraram na brincadeira. E tem mais! Se o adulto Ney
> vai pedir música no Fantástico, esta coluna não sabe, mas hit ele já
> tem. Isto porque “O pai tá on” virou funk na voz de Mc Kekel."

[N.B. Talvez Neymar sabe que "to be on", "You're on!" é dito pelos treinadores em inglês aos jogadores quando se faz substituição. Também se diz: You're up!]

Comment: As definições acabam sendo tão genéricas e encaixam quase em qualquer contexto. Esclarece o uso variado.

Answer (score 1):

Depende da situação. Geralmente rapazes dizem "o pai tá on" quando querem dizer que estão solteiros, ou também pode se encaixar numa ocasião de que eles estão prontos para o que der e vier.

Answer (score 1):

A expressão "O pai tá on" vem de "o pai está online" e costuma ser empregada como sinônimo de "estou na área" ou "estou pronto para o que vier". Expressão muito usada no Whatsapp para indicar que a pessoa está online e que qualquer contato pode chamar para conversar.

Answer (score 1):

"**O pai**" significa que é alguém importante, considerável, grande, valioso, etc.
"**tá on**" pode significar literalmente que a pessoa está online, mas pode significar também que a pessoa chegou em um local.
É uma frase mais usada por jovens.

Answer (score 0):

O uso comum é para dizer dizer que está aberto a relações.

Comment: Olá Samuel, obrigado pela resposta, ainda que parcial - note que a pergunta também pede o contexto em que essa expressão costuma ser usada.

Answer (score 0):

significa estar antenado,ligado,conhecendo determinado assunto.